# Linear algebra problem about projections

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A,B be real matrices of order $n \geq 6$. Let $A + \alpha B$ be
>   projection operator for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> True or false: if A is orthogonal projection, then $A \neq B$.

First, I wrote down the definition of a projection: $A^2 + 2\alpha AB + \alpha^2 B^2 = A + \alpha B$

As A is projection, then $2\alpha AB + \alpha^2 B^2 = \alpha B$. Also, we can divide by $\alpha \neq 0$, i.e.  $2 AB + \alpha B^2 = B$

> What to do next? How to use information that A is orthogonal
>   projection?

Comment: No, the definition for projection is $A^2+\alpha AB+\alpha BA+\alpha^2B^2=A+\alpha B$, since in general $AB\neq BA$.

Comment: thanks, then $AB + BA + aB^2 = B$.

Comment: Does "any" ($\alpha$) mean "some" or does it mean "all"? I wish people would never formulate things in that way; "any" should be reserved for negative (not for any) or questioning (are there any?) phrases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the claim need not be true. For $A=B=0$ all assumptions are satisfied, but $A=B$. Otherwise however it is true. Suppose that $A=B$, and
$A^2=A$ is an orthogonal projection. Then $0=AB+BA+\alpha B^2-B=A+A+\alpha A-A=(\alpha+1)A$ for all $\alpha$.  Hence we have $(\alpha+1)A=0$ for all $\alpha$, so that $A=B=0$, a contradiction. It follows that $A\neq B$.

Answer (score 0):

This one badly formulated, but easy in any reading. Rephrasing slightly, you are asked whether for an orthogonal projection $A$ the fact that $A+\alpha B$ is a projection operator for (some/all) $\alpha$ implies that $A\neq B$. Or by contrapositive whether for an orthogonal projection $A$ the condition $A=B$ implies that $A+\alpha B$ is not a projection operator for (any/some) $\alpha$. Taking the first variant, this is certainly false, taking $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=-1$ as witness (they do produce projection operators). Taking the second variant we see that the implication holds *provided* that $A\neq0$, since then $A^2=A$ implies for instance $(-A)^2\neq-A$, and indeed $A+\alpha A$ is not a projection operator for $\alpha=-2$. However for $A=0$ the implication fails (every $A+\alpha A$ is a projection operator), so one cannot say the statement is *generally* true even with the second reading.

Note that there is no need to even consider the possibility $A\neq B$ at any point. Nor to use that $A$ is orthogonal.